# Mapping areas of Image

Tags: c#, wpf

In my desktop application i want to place a country map and states clickable. On clicking certain state the color of state should change and it should show some state specific info.

What will be the best approach to do it?

-HD

Answer (score 1):

[WPF shapes such as the Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx) are clickable so it is relatively easy to capture a click on a state and change the fill of the shape. The hard part is drawing all the shapes.

Comment: This is something that may be easier in Expression, if you have the time and patience to learn how to do it (it's a powerful tool, but I've found it to have a steep learning curve to get beyond the basics).  Also, if you use Expression, you can do your drawing in Adobe Illustrator (or Photoshop?) and import the file.

Comment: thnx, i was thinking of it after googling for days to find an suitable approach. I need to manage crooked edges though ...

Comment: @Himaushu, You could import an SVG or illustrator file into Expression Blend. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Map_of_USA_with_state_names.svg

Answer (score 0):

You can make image maps with GIMP.  Go here for an official tutorial from GIMP: http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Image_Map/

Now, you'll have to figure the rest out in the programming language you are using. :)